# Owl Carousel 2 Nav on Sides

Tags: javascript, html, css, owl-carousel

Hi I'm using Owl Carousel version 2 and can't find an example to put the navigation on the sides of the carousel like right and left chevrons or arrows. How do you do it?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I just did this yesterday:)

Firstly make sure nav is turned on in the config

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

```
   $('#_samewidth_images').owlCarousel({
      margin:10,
      autoWidth:false,
      nav:true,
      items:4,
      navText : ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>']
  })
```

This will inject the controls into the DOM, see

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-classes.html

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-loaded">
    <div class="owl-stage-outer">
        <div class="owl-stage">
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
            <div class="owl-item">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-controls">
        <div class="owl-nav">
            <div class="owl-prev">prev</div>
            <div class="owl-next">next</div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-dots">
            <div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
            <div class="owl-dot"><span></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next use CSS to position the Next and Prev controls, this is what I used:

```
.owl-prev {
    width: 15px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    display: block !important;
    border:0px solid black;
}

.owl-next {
    width: 15px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    right: -25px;
    display: block !important;
    border:0px solid black;
}
.owl-prev i, .owl-next i {transform : scale(1,6); color: #ccc;}
```

For my icons I used Font Awesome but you could use anything similar. Note the **navText** in the javascript code, this is where you put your custom HTML. I guess you could use an image too (or put it in the background of the .owl-next and .owl-prev divs. Note I used transform to make my arrows higher.

Comment: This classic KevinSol, Thanks.

Comment: why fa-angle-left appearing as vertical bar?

Comment: Do you mean A) a perfect vertical line, or is it B) a deformed > or < ??  If B,  that is that way I wanted it, just remove the transform CSS rule. If A, have you included the font-awesome.min.css file?

Comment: For something very basic you can try navText : ['&lt;','&gt;'], in the javascript

Comment: @KevInSol  Wow.. this is awesome!! Didn't have to change anything in css.. Just copy pasted your code and it worked like charm!! Thanks :)

Comment: The arrows get cut off when page has a width

Comment: another tip: if the `total` number of slides is `less` than the number of `items` shown at once, then the `navs` or `dots` is auto disabled

Answer (score 22):

Just a little bit improvment from @KevinSol answer above.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449552/10933080

This is my JS code:

```
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      loop:true,
      margin:10,
      nav:true,
      navText : ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>','<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
    });
```

and my CSS code:

```
    .owl-prev, .owl-next {
        width: 15px;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        display: block !important;
        border:0px solid black;
    }
    .owl-prev { left: -20px; }
    .owl-next { right: -20px; }
    .owl-prev i, .owl-next i {transform : scale(2,5); color: #ccc;}
```

Comment: Much cleaner.. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Customize Owl Carousel 2 Navigation Arrows**

**Source [Link](https://www.freakyjolly.com/owl-carousel-2-customize-navigation-next-prev-arrows/)**

[image]

**Working Demo [Link](https://freakyjolly.com/demo/jquery/OwlCarousel2/)**

Update the **navText** property

```
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        navText:["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide'></div>"],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3
            }
        }
    });
```

**Add CSS Style**

```
.carousel-wrap {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.owl-carousel .owl-nav{
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot.active span, 
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot:hover span {
    background: #2caae1;
}


.owl-carousel .item {
    text-align: center;
}
.owl-carousel .nav-btn{
    height: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 26px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 100px !important;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-prev.disabled,
.owl-carousel .owl-next.disabled{
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.2;
}

.owl-carousel .prev-slide{
    background: url(nav-icon.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    left: -33px;
}
.owl-carousel .next-slide{
    background: url(nav-icon.png) no-repeat scroll -24px 0px;
    right: -33px;
}
.owl-carousel .prev-slide:hover{
    background-position: 0px -53px;
}
.owl-carousel .next-slide:hover{
    background-position: -24px -53px;
}

span.img-text {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 23px;
    display: block;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
span.img-text:hover {
    color: #2caae1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**HTML markup**

```
 <div id="slider" class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/img/header-img.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/img/header-img.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/img/header-img.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/img/header-img.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="assets/img/header-img.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Css style 
slider is class name**

```
#slider .owl-nav div.owl-prev, 
#slider .owl-nav div.owl-next {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 39px;
    opacity: 0;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
#slider .owl-nav div.owl-prev{
    left: 10%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
}
#slider .owl-nav div.owl-next {
    right: 10%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
}
#slider:hover .owl-nav div.owl-next{
    right: 2%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    opacity: 1;
}
#slider:hover .owl-nav div.owl-prev{
    left: 2%;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    opacity: 1;
}
#slider:hover .owl-nav div.owl-next:hover,
#slider:hover .owl-nav div.owl-prev:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background: #0C94B8;
    border: 1px solid #0C94B8;
}
```

**slider activation**

```
$('#slider').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        items: 1,
        margin:10,
        autoplay: true,
        nav:true,
        navText: ['<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>', '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>']
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using this simple style:

```
.owl-nav button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.owl-prev {
    right: -25px;
}

.owl-next {
    left: -25px;
}

.owl-nav button i {
    font-size: 25px;
    text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
}
```

And the following config:

```
nav: true,
navText: ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
```

Answer (score 1):

***here is my code
for this you need to install bootstrap
code in .HTML file***
i used ngx-owl-carousel-o for this
and installed using npm

[Owl-carousel-o link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel-o)

```
<div class="position-relative">
<owl-carousel-o class="" [options]="customOptions" #owlCar>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let slide of slides   ">
        <ng-template carouselSlide id="slide.id">
            <div class="slider">
                <img class="hvr-grow-shadow p-2 rounded-4" (click)="getid(slide?.id)" [src]="slide?.image"
                    [height]="200" alt="slide.alt" title="slide.title">
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-container>
</owl-carousel-o>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class=" position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle-y" style="z-index: 1;">
        <a class="btn" (click)="owlCar.prev()"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"
                style="font-size: xxx-large; color: white;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class=" position-absolute top-50 end-0 translate-middle-y" style="z-index: 1;">
        <a class="btn" (click)="owlCar.prev()"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"
                style="font-size: xxx-large; color: white;" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my code in .ts file is

```
customOptions: OwlOptions = {
loop: true,
mouseDrag: false,
touchDrag: false,
pullDrag: false,
dots: false,
navSpeed: 100,
autoplay: false,
center: true,
autoplayHoverPause: false,
// navText: [ '<i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>',
//     '<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>'],
responsive: {
  0: {
    items: 1
  },
  400: {
    items: 2
  },
  740: {
    items: 3
  },
  940: {
    items: 4
  }
},
// nav: true
}
```

Hope its Help  [image in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH1mS.png)

Answer (score 0):

**all-slider is class name**

```
 #all-slide .owl-nav div.owl-prev, 
    #all-slide .owl-nav div.owl-next {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-top: -20px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 39px;
        opacity: 0;
        border:1px solid #fff;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
    }
    #all-slide .owl-nav div.owl-prev{
        left: 10%;
        -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: 0.4s;
        -o-transition: 0.4s;
        -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    }
    #all-slide .owl-nav div.owl-next {
        right: 10%;
        -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: 0.4s;
        -o-transition: 0.4s;
        -ms-transition: 0.4s;
    }
    #all-slide:hover .owl-nav div.owl-next{
        right: 2%;
        -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: 0.4s;
        -o-transition: 0.4s;
        -ms-transition: 0.4s;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #all-slide:hover .owl-nav div.owl-prev{
        left: 2%;
        -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
        -moz-transition: 0.4s;
        -o-transition: 0.4s;
        -ms-transition: 0.4s;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #all-slide:hover .owl-nav div.owl-next:hover,
    #all-slide:hover .owl-nav div.owl-prev:hover{
        color:#fff;
        background: #0C94B8;
        border: 1px solid #0C94B8;
    }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do it with some CSS and one arrow in one adge, the other in the other edge without having a margin, but it covering the slider you can use this CSS:

```
.owl-nav button span {
    font-size: 60px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

button.owl-prev {
    float: left;
}

button.owl-next {
    float: right;
}

.owl-nav {
    width: 100vw;
    position: absolute;
}

.owl-carousel.owl-theme.owl-loaded.owl-drag {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```