# OwlCarousel navigation for cards in left and right :react js

Tags: css, reactjs, owl-carousel

I am trying to implement [owl-carousel](/questions/tagged/owl-carousel). I want to show single item at a time and have a next and previous button on left and right of my cards I don't know how to implement that, pls help me.

What I have tried I will add in codesandbox

```
<OwlCarousel
  className="owl-theme"
  loop={true}
  nav={true}
  items={1}
  autoHeight={true}
>
```

Comment: Hi. The codesandbox is not working. In order to help, we should fix it by ourselves. Can you fix it for us so we could play with it?

Comment: @MoshFeu i have updated it to a working codesandbox pls check now

Comment: @MoshFeu if error is comming in first load just refresh the codesand box it will run

Comment: Seems like you have all the elements so if I understand correctly the only thing left is to place the right / left buttons in the slides sides instead of in the bottom? Is that right?

Comment: yes you are correct  @MoshFeu

Comment: By the way - from owl github: "YEAH SO THIS IS PRETTY MUCH DEAD, DO YOURSELF A FAVOR AND SWITCH TO tiny-slider" https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449552/863110) about placing the buttons in non react version of owlcarousel.

Add `navText`

```
navText={[
  '<span class="arrow prev">‹</span>',
  '<span class="arrow next">›</span>'
]}
```

and css

```css
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 26px;
  top: 50%;
}

.arrow:hover {
  background: #869791;
  color: #fff;
}

.next {
  right: 10px;
}

.prev {
  left: 10px;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-surf-982xxs?file=/src/App.js

Note: I have to say that I'm not a big fan of this solution because the buttons remain in their place at the bottom. Only the `span`s moving to the sides but other than that, I think it works well.